# Copy .htaccess (a dotfile) with gulp failed

Tags: .htaccess, gulp, file-copying

In a gulp task, I try to copy files in a build folder.

```
gulp.task( addon, function() {
    var a_addon_function = addon.split("_") ;
    var addon_dirname = a_addon_function[1];
    var dest_path = ( options.env === "tests" || ( options.env === "dist" && options.type === "premium" ) ) ? build_path + addon_dirname + "/" + addon_dirname : build_path + addon_dirname;
    return gulp.src( [ "./plugins/addons/" + addon_dirname + "/**/*", "./plugins/_common/**/*", "./plugins/addons/_common/**/*" ] )
       .pipe( gulp.dest( dest_path ) 
    );
});
```

The file `.htaccess` is never copied. Why ? How to resolve this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Dots
>
> If a file or directory path portion has a . as the first character,
>   then it will not match any glob pattern unless that pattern's
>   corresponding path part also has a . as its first character.
>
> For example, the pattern `a/.*/c` would match the file at `a/.b/c`.
>   However the pattern `a/*/c` would not, because `*` does not start with a
>   dot character. You can make glob treat dots as normal characters by
>   setting dot:true in the options.

Set the option:

```
gulp.src('...…….', { dot: true })
```

so that the dot is treated like any other character.  You should be able to use your original gulp.src then.

From [node-glob documentation](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#dots)

Comment: `dot:true` still works perfectly in 2023

Answer (score 0):

Gulp copy the `.htaccess` file if I add the direct pathto this file : `./plugins/_common/.htaccess`.

```
 gulp.task( addon, function() {
    var a_addon_function = addon.split("_") ;
    var addon_dirname = a_addon_function[1];
    var dest_path = ( options.env === "tests" || ( options.env === "dist" && options.type === "premium" ) ) ? build_path + addon_dirname + "/" + addon_dirname : build_path + addon_dirname;
    return gulp.src( [ "./plugins/addons/" + addon_dirname + "/**/*", "./plugins/_common/**/*", "./plugins/_common/.htaccess", "./plugins/addons/_common/**/*" ] )
       .pipe( gulp.dest( dest_path ) 
   );
});
```

Maybe it is not copied because `.htaccess` has not got extension file.